# Bootstrap & Devise - Not Rendering Proper Alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, alert

By using the default Devise gem settings to generate flash notices, my following code always renders to the `alert-danger` class. See **[bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)**. I'm still fairly new to Rails, please let me know what else code you may want to see.

```
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "danger" %> alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: Maybe right above `<div class="alert ale...`, put `<% p "FLASH----------------->#{ name }" %>`, to write the name you are comparing to the console \output. It may reveal your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check what name is coming out as

```
<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "danger" %>
```

This means that unless name == :notice it renders success otherwise it renders danger

So inspect name and check if it is in fact :notice

Comment: might be worth checking its not `"notice"` rather than `:notice` as `:notice != "notice"`